# Module global variables

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-module

I am using a python program (version 2.7) that imports a module and uses its functions and variables, like demonstrated below.

This is the module.

```
# module.py

variable = 2

def function(number):
    global variable
    variable = number
```

This is the program that uses the module.

```
# program.py

from module import *
print variable
function(1)
print variable
```

The program prints the following:

```
2
2
```

However, if you change `program.py` to this:

```
# program.py

import module
print module.variable
module.function(1)
print module.variable
```

The program prints this:

```
2
1
```

I have no idea why this is happening. Any insight would be helpful.

Thanks,

The Turtle

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is not possible using the `global` keyword.
In python, global variables are only **global** to their **module** and **not shared across modules** (not as in e.g. C). Also see [this PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3104/) for more information about this topic.

Besides, what you're doing in your example is ugly global abuse and leads to unmaintainable and hard to debug programs. There's a better way to do this depending on your exact situation.